# IIS Rewrite URL Decode rule fails

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to convert a url of the structure

```
http://www.xyxyxh.com/ShowItem.aspx%3FID%3D947
```

to

```
http://www.xyxyxh.com/ShowItem.aspx?ID=947
```

I wrote the following url rewrite for IIS 7.5 and above

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Convert" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^ShowItem.aspx/(.+)$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="?q={UrlDecode:{R:1}}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

but the rule fails and the url does not convert. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: your regular expression doesn't match your URL. Get rid of the forward slash after `.aspx`

Comment: @PeterHahndorf Thanks. I tried it with ^ShowItem.aspx(.+)$ but that too fails with "The input data does not match the pattern"

Answer (score 0):

If you check on some url decryption tool for example

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

and paste there

```
http://www.xyxyxh.com/ShowItem.aspx%3FID%3D947
```

and press decode you will see it's

`http://www.xyxyxh.com/ShowItem.aspx?ID=947`

So you need something more then simple url rewrite or maybe you don't need it at all as it it the same?

Simple url rewrite module is useful for example to convert

from:

http://localhost/article/342/some-article-title

to:

http://localhost/article.aspx?id=342&title=some-article-title

You can find more details here:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't answer my question. UrlDecode is the answer but I have not been able to write the correct expression for it.